# Prepared Statement failing with DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -401, SQLSTATE: 42818

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, prepared-statement

I am working on an application which updates data in a database(IBM DB2 v 9.7) via JDBC . Here's The table schema:

Column name    Data Type      Length

1)INDEX                   BIGINT          -

2)USER_NAME      VARCHAR     30

3)SRC                      VARCHAR     30

4)STATUS                VARCHAR     150

5)RT_COUNT         BIGINT           -

And my Code is as:

```
                                      String cmd1="Update ANALYTICS  SET RT_COUNT = 1 WHERE USER_NAME = ? AND STATUS = ?";
                                     PreparedStatement process=connection.prepareStatement(cmd1);

                 process.setString(1, Source);
                 process.setString(2, Content);


                 if(process.executeUpdate()==0)
                 {....
```

But it fails,can anyone help me ?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Please provide the statement you are executing (ie, cmd1) as that is key to solving this.

Comment: In the string cmd1,i have mentioned it as RT_COUNT and USER_NAME so that is not an error..

Answer (score 2):

According to IBM's site, the SQLSTATE of 42818 is 42818 "The operands of an operator or function are not compatible or not comparable.". This means you set the wrong data type to your prepared statement.

You might need to bring the RT_COUNT out and do a setInt or setLong or something to make it work.

Also, I am assuming Source and Content are Strings? If they are not, that may contribute to this as well.

**Edit** 
To do the RT_COUNT thing I was talking about you would have to modify your query to do the following:

```
String cmd1="Update ANALYTICS SET RT_COUNT = ? WHERE USER_NAME = ? AND STATUS = ?";
PreparedStatement process = connection.prepareStatement(cmd1);

process.setLong(1, new Long(1));
process.setString(2, source);
process.setString(3, content);

if(process.executeUpdate()==0)
{....
```

And that might actually be your problem, cause I'm not sure how the driver is interpreting the "1". It needs to be Long to map to bigint in DB2. See for [what data types in Java map to what data types in DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvjdata.html).

Comment: Just as fyi, here is the link for the site with the messages: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/rdb2stt.html

Comment: yes they are Strings.Could you please update me on the RT_COUNT thing?

Comment: And thanks for the Link.But doesn't help,Checked it already:-|

Comment: Does the query works if you execute it by hand with sample values?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Chris Aldrich's answer of casting in Java, if you know what types the parameters should be, you can also cast them in SQL, like so:

```
UPDATE ANALYTICS
   SET RT_COUNT  = CAST(? AS BIGINT)
 WHERE USER_NAME = CAST(? AS VARCHAR(30))
   AND STATUS    = CAST(? AS VARCHAR(150))
```